# how to call resource model methods in Block.php files or phtml files

Tags: blocks, model, resource-model

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I could not call resource model function display records in block/dotnet.php

Comment: The class name `Department_DotNet_Model_dotnetmodel` should be `Department_DotNet_Model_Dotnet`.  The class name `Department_DotNet_Model_Resource_dotnetmodel` should be `Department_DotNet_Model_Resource_Dotnet`.  Capital letters matter here, it might not hurt on your local PC when you trying to run on a linux server it will break.  Blocks do not have a method called `_redirect`, that section of code should be called from a controller instead. It is bad practice to use any resource model from a block, keep that stuff to the regular model only.

Comment: @clockworkgeek thanks for suggestion, I will follow the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Mage::getModel('dotnet/dotnet')->displayrecods()` use:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('dotnet/dotnetmodel')->displayrecods()
```

Or better yet in your model (`dotnet/dotnet`) create a method named `displayrecords` so you will be able to use your original code. That method can look like this:

```
public function displayrecods(){
    return $this->_getResource()->displayrecods();
}
```

So this method will act like a wrapper for the method in the resource model.
**[EDIT]**
I think the problem is with your resource model declaration in `config.xml`

```
<dotnet_resource>
    <class>Departmen_DotNet_Model</class>
...
```

Should be

```
<dotnet_resource>
    <class>Departmen_DotNet_Model_Resource</class>
...
```

---

<sub>Next time post code, not screenshots of it</sub>

Comment: thanks for reply marius, either of the options are not helpful

Comment: @prasadmaganti. Actually they are (or will be after you fix the error), but I've re-read the error message, more careful this time. Can you post your `config.xml` file in the question. I see that actually `Mage::getModel('dotnet/dotnet')` returns null. Also does the file `Department_DotNet_Model_DotNet` exist?

Comment: @prasadmaganti. I've also edited my answer. Try again with the first option.

Comment: i could not call model/resource function and model based function in my block/.php or phtml file. please help me. i have struck on this

Comment: @prasadmaganti.Then post your entire module in the question. So we can reproduce it.

Comment: when i tried with echo var_dump('dotnet/dotnet') displays false. what does it means. and the config.xml files is  <models>
            <dotnet>
                <class>Department_DotNet_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>dotnet_resource</resourceModel>
            </dotnet>
            <dotnet_resource>
                <class>Department_DotNet_Model</class>
                <entities>
                    <dotnet>
                        <table>dotnet</table>
                    </dotnet>
                </entities>
            </dotnet_resource>

Comment: Department_DotNet_Model_DotNet file exists. i have tried here to call resource model file, which doesn't work

Comment: i could not attach no more files here, how could i send entire module here... plz advise

Comment: @prasadmaganti. Post the code in the question not in the comments.

Comment: i have attached config.xml and model file in the question. thanx for help

Comment: @prasadmaganti. I've edited the answer